# Spring Boot testing with Spring Security. How does one launch an alternative security config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

My spring boot application has an Application class. When I run it (as an application), it launches itself within an embedded servlet container (Tomcat, in my case). Somehow (through Application's @annotations, I suppose), WebSecurityConfig (extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) in the same package is loaded.

WebSecurityConfig contains two important blocks of configuration information:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // enables method-level role-checking
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth
         .ldapAuthentication()
         .userSearchBase("CN=Users,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com")   
         .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
         .groupSearchBase("OU=Groups,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com")                 
         .groupSearchFilter("(member={0})")
         .contextSource()
            .managerDn("cn=ad-bind,cn=users,dc=some,dc=domain,dc=com")
            .managerPassword("APASSWORD!") 
            .url("ldaps://some.domain.com:636");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("***************** WebSecurityConfig.configure *************************");
         http.csrf().disable();

         http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable();

         http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/images/*", "/me", "/products", "/product/**", "/offerings", "/offering/**", "/client/**")
                            .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/me")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();

         http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/me");
    }
}
```

configureGlobal() contains the configuration for our internal LDAP system and it works just fine.

configure() specifies which URLs are public, which are only to be shown to logged-in users and which relative URLs to send users to as they log in.

Now I'm into integration testing and have written some methods to test controllers that do not require authentication. Those tests work as expected. The Application class fires up and the tests execute against it.

But now I want to test controller methods that DO require authentication. The way I think this is accomplished is by telling the test class to fire up an alternative Application class (TestApplication, in my case) and WebSecurityConfig that creates dummy users:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class) // fires up with TestApplication.class instead of Application.class
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProductControllerTests {
    // test methods here, this time with username/password included
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<TestApplication> applicationClass = TestApplication.class;

}

@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("testuser").password("userpass").roles("USER");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("testadmin").password("adminpass").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("***************** WebSecurityConfig.configure *************************");
         http.csrf().disable();

         http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                    .disable();

         http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/images/*", "/me", "/products", "/product/**", "/offerings", "/offering/**", "/client/**")
                            .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/me")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll();

         http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/me");
    }
}
```

So my question is: When I execute the unit test class, I believe TestApplication is firing. However, it is NOT picking up the alternative WebSecurityConfig class and its auth.inMemoryAuthentication() test users. **How do I force my application to use one WebSecurityConfig when running the application normally, but a different WebSecurityConfig when running the unit tests?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your `TestApplication` to include just the beans that you would like to test. In other words, make sure that your `WebSecurityConfig` is not part of the test configuration. If you read the [javadoc of @SpringBootApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) you will notice that it is a composite annotation that consists of (among others) the [@ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) annotation. Consequently your `Application` and your `TestApplication` will perform a recursive scan from the package in which the class is located. The Spring reference docs has a specific chapter about [Using filters to customize scanning](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters).

Alternatively, if you are using Spring Security version 4 or greater you may find the additions of [@WithMockUser](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser) and [@WithUserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withuserdetails) interesting.

Comment: Yep I figured it out and came back to write an answer, but you nailed it as well. Thanks for saving me the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

In your security configuration class, add @Profile annotation to disable in unit test profile. like:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_UNITTEST)
public class WebSecurityConfig { ....}
```

And let your another security config for test just in test dir.